# unable to trigger select all option of checkbox on individual item check change

Tags: wpf, mvvm

In a window got a lisbox which is bind to a list which is of type **Employee** having checkbox adjacent to each employee name and can be selected individually.

Got another control check box with "select all" option.

I'm able to do "select all" "select none" easily by binding the select all checkbox's isChecked to a property **IsSelectAllChecked** in my viewModel.

However if select all option is true and every employee items in lisbox is checked.. 
if one of item I uncheck how can I remove check from select all option checkbox.

```
 <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <CheckBox Margin="20,15,0,15" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelectAllChecked}">
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Select All" />
    </CheckBox>
```

can anybody advise

Answer (score 0):

The `IsChecked` of the checkboxes for the employees should also have a binding to an `IsSelected` property of the employee viewmodel. In the setter of that property you can evaluate if changes to `IsSelectAllChecked` are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

Here is your Select All `Checkbox` and the bound property:

```
<CheckBox Margin="20,15,0,15" Content="Select all"
     IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelectAllChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

public bool IsSelectAllChecked
{
  get
  {
     return isSelectAllChecked
  }
  set
  {
    isSelectAllChecked = value;
    // Do some code here to turn all selected booleans to true
    SelectAll();
    OnPropertyChanged("IsSelectAllChecked"); // Fire OnPropertyChanged event, important for TwoWay Binding!!
}
```

Note that the `Binding` for your `CheckBox` is now in `TwoWay` mode, and with `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` . This will allow:

- to change value of the bound property from the code ( `TwoWay` )
- to update the `CheckBox` state when the value is updated ( `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` )

Up next: here is one of your checkboxes and the equivalent in code

```
<CheckBox  Content="Select one"
     IsChecked="{Binding Path=OneOfYourBools, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

public bool OneOfYourBools
{
  get
  {
     return oneOfYourBools;
  }
  set
  {
    oneOfYourBools = value;
    // If the isAllSelected was true, turn it to false!
    if (this.IsSelectAllChecked)
    {
       this.IsSelectAllChecked = false;
    }
    OnPropertyChanged("OneOfYourBools"); // Fire OnPropertyChanged event, important for TwoWay Binding!!
}
```

And this should do the trick : when one `bool` is updated, the `selectAll` bool is updated as well, and vice versa